# Multiple instances of inner classes in Python

Tags: python, class, inner-classes

I'm trying to create a Child class within a Person class, but am having trouble accessing the child object after creation, when more than one instance is created dynamically.

For example, I ask the user how many kids they have, and I then want to create an instance of the inner child class for each child they have, and be able to access that information later.

Here is some code that I have tried so far, which works for one child. But I can't figure out how to access the information if they have more than 1 child.

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, age):
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.age = age
    self.numberOfChildren = 0

  class Child:
   def __init__(self, firstName, age):
     self.firstName = firstName
     self.age = age

   def show(self):
     print(self.firstName, self.age)

client = Person("Jake", "Blah", 31)

numberOfChildren = input("How many kids do you have?")
client.numberOfChildren = 2

for i in range(numberOfChildren):
  firstName = input("What is the name of your child?")
  age = input("how old is your child?")
  child = client.Child(firstName, age)
  child.show()
```

This correctly prints out the child, and seems to create the object within the Person class, but I can not figure out how to access this information through the Person class (client).

If I use something like child.firstName, it obviously only shows the last one entered, as the for loop is over-writing the child object every time. If I knew in advance how many children they would have, I could use something like child1, child2, etc, but since it is dynamic I don't know in advance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you've pasted isn't valid Python code (there are multiple things wrong with it). It can't possibly print anything correctly.

Comment: Sorry copy paste error, should be good now.

Comment: Does `Child` have to be an inner class?  This would be much easier if it weren't.

Comment: Why is `Child` a different class at all? What makes a child different from a person?

Comment: Also you seem to be confused on the actual variable name -- is it `numberOfKids` or `numChildren` ?

Comment: `Person` should have a `self.children: list` variable. Then you should have a `Person.add_child()` method that appends the child to the list.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning and wasn't sure if it should be a inner class or not. The idea is to have a class which contains a specific person, that also has the info for that persons children, spouse, job, etc.

I was thinking since the person can have multiple children, and each child will be a different age/gender/height/etc, it might be better to make that an inner class rather than a method within the main class (whereas they are only likely to have one spouse for example).

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't design them as inner classes. Depending on what you want to model in the end, I'd maybe just have a single `Person` model with `parents` and `children` lists (or sets).

Comment: What you're asking for would be reasonable in Java and other languages, where a `Child` object would have both `self` referring to itself and `Person.self` referring to the enclosing class.  That's not how Python works.  Inner classes are just separate classes.  Except for the fact that you call the inner class `Person.Child`, it really has no relationship to any particular person unless you specify that yourself.

Comment: Great, thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd design this with a single `Person` class like

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, age):
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.age = age
        self.children = set()
        self.parents = set()

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.add(child)
        child.parents.add(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Person({self.firstName!r}, {self.lastName!r}, age {self.age}, {len(self.children)} kids)"


client = Person("Jake", "Blah", 31)
child_1 = Person("Bob", "Blah", 1)
child_2 = Person("Penny", "Blah", 2)
client.add_child(child_1)
client.add_child(child_2)
print(client, "- kids:", client.children)
print(child_1, "- parents:", child_1.parents)
```

This prints out

```
Person('Jake', 'Blah', age 31, 2 kids) - kids: {Person('Penny', 'Blah', age 2, 0 kids), Person('Bob', 'Blah', age 1, 0 kids)}
Person('Bob', 'Blah', age 1, 0 kids) {Person('Jake', 'Blah', age 31, 2 kids)}
```